# PHP Mirror API: Blank Page After Authenitication

Tags: google-mirror-api

I recently setup a Google Glass Mirror API Quickstart (PHP) and after being redirected to Google for authentication and sent back to my site, the Quickstart shows a blank page. The URL still has all the auth info and my main page for demonstration is blank too.

I've installed it as per to the guide on Google's site and in their videos. Does anyone have a solution or have had this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem.  I don't know if its something I did wrong or if its something I missed.